# Zend Framework 2 and AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, zend-framework2

Trying to implement a ZF2 app using AngularJS for all my frontend. I've got the ZF app setup and going, but I'm not sure how to go about making only 1 layout.html for the entire app with will contain the `<div data-ng-view></div>`?

I guess this really boils down to: How do I implement 1 global layout.html file in ZF2 where I have multiple modules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't know already, ZF2 module configuration is all smashed together into one big configuration. The order that the modules are listed in your `config/application.config.php` depicts the order in which modules are loaded.

Once you realise this, you can use this to your advantage - in the last module that loads (for example your `Application` module, make sure you configure the layout there. An example layout configuration might look like this:

```
return array(
    'view_manager' => array(
        'template_map' => array(
            'layout/layout' => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/layout.phtml'
        ),
    ),
);
```

This can be seen in the [ZF2 skeleton application](https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication/blob/master/module/Application/config/module.config.php#L86).

In most instances (not all), I'd recommend that your `Application` module is the last module loaded.